# Creating a moving text on div on mouse hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm creating a Metro UI themed website, and I want to know how can I achieve moving text on mouse hover on the tiles. I want to achieve something like the hover effects on [this webpage](http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/windows8-animations/demo/index.html).

```
<div style="background:#F0514A; width:400px; height:200px;">TEXT !</div>
```

Comment: It looks like the tiles are already doing what you suggest.

Comment: I have created various tile. but i want to create a moving text on hover like the one in example

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery to build this, I'd suggest calling jQuery animations from a [.mouseenter()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [.mouseleave()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) event handler. You can get the content to slide using the [Slide Effect](http://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/) that comes with jQuery UI. From what you're doing, it looks like you either want a negative `z-index` in the CSS to hide the content and allow it to appear like it's sliding in.